# Custom Object / Entity Properties / Functions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

What is the best practice for creating custom properties / functions for Doctrine Objects/Entites ?

For example in Symfony1.4 / Doctrine 1.2 I could add a method to the `User` class

```
public function getName()
{
  return $this->getFirstName().' '.$this->getLastName();
}
```

This would combine to fields and return the value - a custom property / function.

Now where the heck do i do this in Symfony2 / Doctrine 2 - the entity class ? is it OK to put custom methods in there ? I am using the EntityRepositories for custom methods to find data ... but not sure on the best way to do it for an object.

I have searched high and low and **cannot** find anything related to this in the documentation (both Symfony and Doctrine) .... please put me out of my misery !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Doctrine entity is really just a plain old PHP object, with additional mapping information on how to persist some or all of the properties of the object to the database. You can add anything you want to the class, and not all properties or methods have to map to a field in the database.

For your specific concern, your `getName()` method is just fine as far as best practice goes. Note that to *update* the fields, you'd either have to use the `setFirstName()` and `setLastName()` methods, or perhaps write a `setName()` method that explodes on a space and updates the individual fields.

Comment: I just found it strange that in the docs for Symfony1.4 / Doctrine 1.2 the example is given - ie to change the model class - but there is no clear indication on how to do this on Symfony2 / Doctrine 2 - I have actually implemented as you suggested - just wanted to check i was doing it 'correctly' ... thanks for your answer

Comment: That's what I use for some fields with calculated result. Weird that the doc doesnt mention it, I tried it just because it made sense to me and it worked.